# Redirection (oscommerce)

Tags: php, oscommerce

I'm facing a problem here when my clients order products from my shop online.
When they order by Bank card or Paypal it works fine but when when they order by cheque/check or bank transfer they they land on the wrong confirm page (shopping_cart) and not (checkout_success) !

What should I do to correct this?

Comment: I think we'd need to see more of your code, preferably in Minimally Verifiable, Correct Example (MVCE) form.

Comment: It's an oscommerce site so there's too much files and I didn't know what file should I change so i can fix the problem

Comment: Which oscommerce version are you using? Which checkout module(s) are you using? From the little info above I'd start by verifying the correct settings have been entered on the PayPal side in manager (i.e. The correct return url).

Comment: CRE-Loaded6_FR_SP1.2 it's the version of oscommerce ,
moneyorder for the payment Payment by cheque
paypalipn  for paypal 
virementbancaire for the transfer by bank, I Have no problem with Paypal but with the others @ndiggity